# L'emploi de « ladite » en un mot prévaut-il toujours sur l'emploi de « la dite » en deux mots ?

Tags: orthographe

L'extrait suivant illustre-t-il une faute commune de l'usage de « ladite » ?

> Et il est probable que la branche palestinienne des Frères musulmans réintégrera la dite liste.

Ainsi, ne devrions-nous pas écrire plutôt ce qui suit ?

> Et il est probable que la branche palestinienne des Frères musulmans réintègrera ladite liste.

N.B.: En aucun cas je ne veux politiser ce message, je ne fais que citer une phrase d'un [article de presse](http://www.france24.com/fr/20141217-parlement-europeen-botte-touche-palestine-justice-hamas-ue-reconnaissance-onu/).

Comment: http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/le-dit-ou-ledit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En ce qui concerne la règle des mots composés d'un article et du mot "dit" ou "dite":

> On écrit en un seul mot les termes composés d’un article et de « dit »
>   ou de « dite ».

Donc on écrira:

*Ladite fillette va porter un petit pot de beurre à sa grand-mère.*

> Il en va de même pour « susdit » et « susdite ».

Donc on écrira:

*La grand-mère susdite a fini dans le ventre du loup.*

Le fait de ne pas agglutiner ces deux mots est donc bien une faute.